# How to batch watermark images with an unique identifier?

Tags: gimp, batch

I know how to use BIMP in GIMP, but I have 20 photos that I want to batch watermark them with different letters A-Z or different numbers 1-20. So one photo is A the other B and so on.

Comment: If you're willing to use some command-line magic, get ready to run!

Comment: No way! It is possible?? What's the command please?

Comment: Please take a look at the example and tell me if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `bash` script to accomplish this task using `convert` from ImageMagick :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change the working directory to the one specified as argument.
if ! cd "$*"; then
    echo "error: the folder '$*' doesn't exist."
    exit
fi

# Create a directory called "output" into the working directory.
mkdir output &> /dev/null

# Start counting in 1.
counter=1

# For each file that ends in .jpg:
for image in *.jpg; do  
    convert "$image" \
            -background transparent \
            -fill grey \
            -font ubuntu \
            -size 280x160 \
            -pointsize 28 \
            -gravity southeast \
            -annotate +0+0 "TEXT: $counter" \
            "output/$image"

    # Increment counter by one.
    ((counter++)) 
done
```

**Usage:** `bash watermark.sh /home/$USER/folder`

---

Remember to adjust the path to the folder with the images and change the appearance or position of the watermark.

Comment: Time to eat my hat and run around naked! Thank you for this, it works brilliantly https://i.imgur.com/Lu8Vudl.jpg. Next stranger I meet, will be a lucky person indeed because a free coffee for them. Thanks again, you made my day.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​ You're welcome! I hope you won't do everything at once.